# '[String]?' does not have a member named 'count' in Swift

Tags: swift

I have the following swift code:

```
var Data = ["first" : ["Rob ", "Gladys", "Hugh"],
"last" : ["Banks", "Friday", "Mungus"]
]

var elementCount = 0
var key = "first"
var elements = data[key!]
elementCount = elements.count
```

but I get the following error on the last line of this code:

```
'[String]?' does not have a member named 'count'
```

How do I fix this error and why is it happening?

** **EDIT** **

What if I also wanted to extract the item within `elements` at a particular index. So, for example:

```
var myIndex = 1

var firstname = elements[myIndex]
```

this gives the error

```
'[String]?' does not have a member named 'subscript'
```

Comment: Your `!` is in the wrong place. You need to unwrap the returned value, not the key itself.

Comment: You might also want to use the `countElements(_:)` function.

Comment: To subscript an optional array, you can write `elements?[myIndex]`.  Note, you should try experimenting with the various optional techniques (`if let`, `??`, `.map`, `?.` rather than resorting to `!`, since it is dangerous when your code isn’t guaranteed to return a value every time (say if they key isn’t always present)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means your dictionary returns an optional array and you need to unwrap it before trying to access its property count. You have to do like this:

```
let data = ["first" : ["Rob ", "Gladys", "Hugh"],"last" : ["Banks", "Friday", "Mungus"]]

var elementCount = 0
let key = "first"
if let elements = data[key] {
    elementCount = elements.count
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, `let elementCount = data[key]?.count ?? 0`